# smooth scroll jquery script works in chrome but dont works in firefox?? why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Works fine in google chrom but dont works in firefox.
I got some bad code or its a browser problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#menu a").click(function(){
    var faqId = $(this).attr("href");
    $("body").animate({scrollTop: $(faqId).offset().top}, "slow");
    return false;
});

    $("#footer a").click(function(){
    var faqId = $(this).attr("href");
    $("body").animate({scrollTop: $(faqId).offset().top}, "slow");
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support Firefox, animate the HTML tag too:

```
$("body, html").animate(...);
```